# Transform XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm formatting an xml file with a simple XSL which works fine when there is no additional data in the container tag but doesnt display any data if there is data in the tag.

When the XML is like this it's fine

```
<Result>
 <primaryTopic> 
  <CompanyName>ZENITH PRINT (UK) LIMITED</CompanyName>
  <RegAddress>
    <AddressLine1>ZENITH HOUSE</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine2>MOY ROAD INDUSTRIAL ESTATE</AddressLine2>
    <PostTown>TAFFS WELL</PostTown>
    <County>CARDIFF</County>
    <Postcode>CF15 7QR</Postcode>
  </RegAddress>
```

When there is url data in the tag like this it fails

```
<Result xmlns="http://#####.uk/terms/xxx">
 <primaryTopic> 
  <CompanyName>ZENITH PRINT (UK) LIMITED</CompanyName>
  <RegAddress href="http://#####.uk/doc/company/02050399#RegAddress">
    <AddressLine1>ZENITH HOUSE</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine2>MOY ROAD INDUSTRIAL ESTATE</AddressLine2>
    <PostTown>TAFFS WELL</PostTown>
    <County>CARDIFF</County>
    <Postcode>CF15 7QR</Postcode>
  </RegAddress>
```

The XSL I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="Result/primaryTopic/CompanyName"/></h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Company Name</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Result/primaryTopic/CompanyName"/></td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Result/primaryTopic/RegAddress/AddressLine1"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the failing message? or what did you expected what did you see

Comment: Can't reproduce, both XMLs give the same output here.

Comment: Is the '#####' in the url ACTUALLY '#####'? Or are those characters you've changed to anonymise? Note characters <, & and " are not allowed in XML attributes.

Comment: There is no error message. It just shows the CompanyName data and nothing else. I was expecting it to display the data from ADDRESSLINE1 (ZENITH HOUSE) after that.

Comment: The ####.co.uk is just to hide the url. It's formatted correctly in the XML

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Where I changed the xml to get it to work locally I didnt correct the RESULT tag to the format I'm receiving it. This is what the RESULT tag contains <Result xmlns="http://www.#####.uk/terms/xxx">. When this is removed and replaced with <Result> it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for the second sample, a default namespace has been specified, and so all the elements in the XML will be part of that namespace

```
<Result xmlns="http://#####.uk/terms/xxx">
```

However, your XSLT is looking for elements which have no namespace, and so it won't match the elements in the XML, which do have a namespace.

The solution is to make sure the namespace is part of your XSLT when you match the elements

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xxx="http://#####.uk/terms/xxx" exclude-result-prefixes="xxx">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>
               <xsl:value-of select="xxx:Result/xxx:primaryTopic/xxx:CompanyName"/>
            </h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <td>Company Name</td>
                  <td>
                     <xsl:value-of select="xxx:Result/xxx:primaryTopic/xxx:CompanyName"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>Address</td>
                  <td>
                     <xsl:value-of select="xxx:Result/xxx:primaryTopic/xxx:RegAddress/xxx:AddressLine1"/>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, this will only work on your second XML sample, not the first. If you want an XSLT that will work with both samples, you could do something like this to check for element names regardless of namespace.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/*/*[local-name()='primaryTopic']">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>
               <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'CompanyName']"/>
            </h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <td>Company Name</td>
                  <td>
                     <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'CompanyName']"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>Address</td>
                  <td>
                     <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'RegAddress']/*[local-name() = 'AddressLine1']"/>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should give the same output for both the first and second XML samples.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL works fine for both XMLs. There must be something else going wrong. Adding a attribute to a XML node must not effect the transformation.